# Ignore or use WHERE clause in T-SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @FirstChar VarChar(1) = '*'
DECLARE @SortOrder VarChar(1) = 'C'
```

1st query

```
SELECT
    aCode,
    aName,
    aAddress,
    aPhone
FROM 
    [Agency]
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN @SortOrder = 'C' THEN aCode
        WHEN @SortOrder = 'N' THEN aName
    END
```

2nd query:

```
SELECT
    aCode,
    aName,
    aAddress,
    aPhone
FROM 
    [Agency]
WHERE 
    @SortOrder = 'C' 
    AND SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(aCode)), 1, 1) LIKE '%' + @FirstCha
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN @SortOrder = 'C' THEN aCode
        WHEN @SortOrder = 'N' THEN aName
    END
```

If `@FirstChar ="*"` I want to get all rows (1st query). If `@FirstChar <> '*'`, I want to get only the rows matching the value of parameter (2nd query).

- If `@SortOrder = "C"` & If `@FirstChar = "*"` I want all rows sorted by `aCode`
- If `@SortOrder = "N"` & If `@FirstChar = "*"`, I want all rows sorted by `aName`

My question is: how to use one query without using above two queries to get my result.

**After Below Modification my query running (Thanks FAB)**

```
SELECT
aCode,
aName,
aAddress,
aPhone
FROM [Agency] 
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN @FirstChar = '*' THEN 1
    END = 1
    OR 
                case when @SortOrder = 'C' then SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(aCode)), 1, 1)
                else SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(aName)), 1, 1)
            end = @FirstChar
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN @SortOrder = 'C' THEN aCode
        WHEN @SortOrder = 'N' THEN aName
    END
```

Comment: Note that for dynamic search conditions like this, you often also want `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`, or completely separate queries with an `IF`, to avoid query plans caching only one set of parameter values. See [Erland Sommarskog's excellent article](https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) on the various aspects and pitfalls.

Comment: Forcing all executions through a single (static, general purpose) SQL Statement is usually a mistake. The article linked above has A Lot of detail, but it's well worth reading. If you don't read it, abide by this maxim; if you want customised behaviour, execute a customised SQL Statement.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is probably the right way to go, especially when you have such differing queries

Comment: After doing some modification to FAB's solution my code is working. Please refer modified section. Thanks FAB.

Comment: `CASE WHEN @FirstChar = '*' THEN 1 END = 1` is a roundabout way of just saying `@FirstChar = '*'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd take Jeroen's advice and leave this as 2 different queries within **IF** conditions, however if your situation really requires, something like this may work:

```sql
DECLARE @FirstChar VarChar(1) = '*'
DECLARE @SortOrder VarChar(1) = 'C'

SELECT
    aCode,
    aName,
    aAddress,
    aPhone
FROM 
    [Agency]
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN @FirstChar = '*' THEN 1
        ELSE IIF(@SortOrder = 'C', 1, 0)
    END = 1
    AND
        CASE
            WHEN @FirstChar != '*' THEN @FirstChar
            ELSE SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(aCode)), 1, 1)
        END = SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(aCode)), 1, 1)
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN @SortOrder = 'C' THEN aCode
        WHEN @SortOrder = 'N' THEN aName
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @FirstChar VarChar(1) = '*'
DECLARE @SortOrder VarChar(1) = 'C'

SELECT
    aCode,
    aName,
    aAddress,
    aPhone
FROM 
    [Agency]
WHERE 
    (@FirstChar = '*' OR SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(aCode)), 1, 1) LIKE '%' + @FirstChar)
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN @SortOrder = 'C' THEN aCode
        WHEN @SortOrder = 'N' THEN aName
    END
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

This query uses a `WHERE` clause that filters the results based on the value of the `@FirstChar` variable. If `@FirstChar` equals '*', all agencies in the [Agency] table are selected. If `@FirstChar` has another value, only agencies whose code starts with that value are selected. The query continues to sort the results based on the value of the `@SortOrder` variable, using the same `CASE` expression.

`OPTION(RECOMPILE)` can be used in this combined query because the `WHERE` clause uses an expression that depends on the values ​​of the `@FirstChar` and aCode variables. Depending on the value of `@FirstChar`, the expression can vary significantly and have an impact on query performance.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
WHERE @FirstCha in ('*', SUBSTRING(LTRIM(aCode), 1, 1))
```

or

```
WHERE @FirstCha = '*' OR @FirstCha = SUBSTRING(LTRIM(aCode), 1, 1))
```

The second one is probably more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use dynamic sql to avoid the issues that @Jeroen Mostert
mentioned, but for static code solution i would probably do something like this:

```sql
DECLARE @FirstChar VarChar(1) = '*'
DECLARE @SortOrder VarChar(1) = 'C'

IF @FirstChar = '*'
  SET @FirstChar = '%'

SELECT
    aCode,
    aName,
    aAddress,
    aPhone
FROM 
    [Agency]
WHERE LEFT(LTRIM(aCode), 1) + ' ' LIKE @FirstChar
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN @SortOrder = 'C' THEN aCode
        WHEN @SortOrder = 'N' THEN aName
    END
```

`IF @FirstChar = '*' SET @FirstChar = '%'`
Here I simplify the case where first char is * and exchange it with '%'. This allows LIKE code to match anything.

`LEFT(LTRIM(aCode), 1) LIKE @FirstChar`
Here i removed unnecessary RTRIM since it's not needed here, finally i use LEFT cause SUBSTRING is overkill here

Downside of this solution is that the code will do a search in both cases, but i think it will happened in the other answer's more complicated OR conditions as well. This is why dynamic SQL would be king here, because it can avoid WHERE condition altogether.